# Inserting strings every so many lines with awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to insert command strings and having difficulty with my syntax. I'm trying to get the "mv" every other line, "sleep" every third line and "wait" every 4th line. Here is what I got and been playing with different combinations. Any help would be appreciated.

```
awk '{ print; print "mv $NEWEST $RNAME"; }' curl.txt > mv.txt
sleep 2
wait
awk 'NR==3{ print "sleep 2"; }1' mv.txt > sleep.txt
sleep 2
wait
awk 'NR==4{ print "wait"; }1' sleep.txt > wait.txt
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions) and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `NR==3` will be true solely for the 3rd line of input; if the intention is to dom something for *every 3rd line* then you need to employ the modulo operator, eg, `(NR%3)==0`; not sure what the purpose of the `sleep2;wait` is (especially since there are no backgrounded jobs), but you should be able to replace this entire set of code with a single `awk` script, though seeing a sample set of input and expected output would help in understanding the overall requirement

Comment: In case it's what you have in mind, do not execute the output of `print "mv $NEWEST $RNAME"` as that'll leave your variables exposed to the shell for interpretation. You probably want `print "mv -- \"$NEWEST\" \"$RNAME\""` but it's hard to tell without more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but wouldn't this be enough?

```sh
awk '{ printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", $0, "mv $NEWEST $RNAME", "sleep 2", "wait" }' curl.txt
```

Comment: I'm working on something for myself and just want to check the outputs through the process. this worked the charm. thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ seq 5 | sed '1~1a mv $NEWEST $RNAME\nsleep 2\nwait'

1
mv $NEWEST $RNAME
sleep 2
wait
2
mv $NEWEST $RNAME
sleep 2
wait
3
mv $NEWEST $RNAME
sleep 2
wait
4
mv $NEWEST $RNAME
sleep 2
wait
5
mv $NEWEST $RNAME
sleep 2
wait
```

you can change the starting line number and the frequency with `1~1`